# Why after sorting merged lists I receive None instead the merged list when printing it?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have two lists that I slice to show only the first m elements for the first list and the first n elements for the second list.

Then I merge then.

Thereafter I sort the result list, but when I print it, I receive `None` instead the merged list sorted.

Why?

```
nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
m = 3
nums2 = [2,5,6]
n = 2

nums1 = nums1[:m] #output = [1, 2, 3]
nums2 = nums2[:n] #output = [2, 5]

nums1 = nums1 + nums2 #output = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5]
nums1 = nums1.sort()

print(nums1)
#expected output is [1, 2, 2, 3, 5]
#but receive None
```

Comment: Just use `nums1.sort()` instead of `nums1 = nums1.sort()`

Comment: Here is another good article on the subject: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz yes, I knew that only with nums1.sort, it works, but I'd like to know why with nums1=nums1.sort() it doesn't. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil - `num1.sort()` returns `None`. The list is sorted in-place.

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil It's written exactly like this in the other question's accepted answer : `The general design principle in Python is for functions that mutate an object in-place to return None` So, that's by design of Python

Comment: Logically when you assign a `variable` to a inbuilt function the output will be `returned` to `var` which is assigned...In this `developers` built sort function such that it won't return anything...It will directly applies logic on list....Normally a function returns somethings...If not so it be logically `None`

Comment: https://app.codingrooms.com/w/bZwXlInqPsm2 see I've created example for you

Comment: `help(list.sort)` provides you with all the necessary information.
If you prefer a more "functional-progamming" way to do it, i.e. obtain a result without altering the original list, prefer the `sorted()` builtin function.